# Export to ppt report. Any suggestions

Tags: report, powerpoint

We have a UI application built using angularjs, Django framework and oracle as database.The user would like to download the data as a ppt report. The reports will have multiple tabular data and charts. The pptx libraries are not an option given, since there are some issues raised. The tableExport.js supports xls and not ppt.Is there any other way. Thanks.

Comment: The latest version (1.5.0) of [PptxGenJS](https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS/issues) includes the ability to create all the core chart types (area, bar, line and pie). A sample presentation can be generated from the [project website](https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [PptxGenJS](http://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS) already to create a module based on their product for your application? More info at gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS

PptxGenJS supports Tables, Shapes, Images, Text and Media and works on Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Opera and IE11. Might be worth a look, check their API: http://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/ or GitHub repo: https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have tried pptxgenjs, but it does not support charts that I need to incorporate.